# PHP DOMDocument createElement obfuscates ampersand

Tags: php, obfuscation, domdocument

I am using PHP DOMDocument library in order to create a 'script' tag element with a, well, a javascript value and insert it in the DOM.

This is what I do:

```
$scriptElement = $doc->createElement('script',$scriptTagVal);
echo $scriptElement->nodeValue;                                                                  
$someNode->parentNode->insertBefore($scriptElement,$postRttScriptNode);
```

This behaves the way I expect it to, it inserts an element right before 'someNode'. However, it does something strange, it obfuscates the ampersand (&). Single Ampersands (&) do not exist, and double Ampersands (&&) are bought down to single ampersands.

Crazy? Well, I tried doing this:

```
$scriptElement = $doc->createElement('script','return "undefined" !== typeof b **&&** null !== b ? b.getAttribute("content") : 0');
```

And if I echo out $scriptElement->nodeValue,

I get

```
return "undefined" !== typeof b **&** null !== b ? b.getAttribute("content") : 0'
```

I am assuming this is virtually unheard of, but I tried creating different elements with values that contain double ampersands. Something like:

```
 $scriptElement = $doc->createElement('p','Why does DOMDocument obfuscate double
            ampersands(&&)');
```

And the result that is outputted to my browser is a

tag with the value:

**Why does DOMDocument obfuscate double
                ampersands(**

Special characters perhaps? Is there anyway I can get around this? I mean, surely there has to be a way to use DOMDocument to insert javascript in HTML, right?

Comment: Because you need to encode it. THis question has been answered many times.

Comment: *The value will not be escaped. Use DOMDocument::createTextNode() to create a text node with escaping support.* http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As noted in http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php

> The value will not be escaped. Use DOMDocument::createTextNode() to
>   create a text node with escaping support

With that you can try:

```
$doc = new DomDocument();
$scriptContent = 'return "undefined" !== typeof b **&&** null !== b ? b.getAttribute("content") : 0';
$scriptElement = $doc->createElement('script');
$scriptElement->appendChild($doc->createTextNode($scriptContent));
$doc->appendChild($scriptElement);
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

you may need to use `$doc->ownerDocument->createTextNode()` when building your text node, this is untested as I don't have a run-able code snippet.

Comment: I can't figure out where the `$value` parameter even comes from. The corresponding [WEB API](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-document-createelement) it's supposed to mimic doesn't have it.